# Calculate Monthly Variability by Long-Term Average Pandas

Tags: pandas, row, calculated-columns, calculation

i have data that looks like this in dataframe "YM"showing the values for the year 2019 for months 8-12:

```
     year    month  adjusted_power
343  2019    08     20754.20750
344  2019    09     20305.95125
345  2019    10     18428.88125
346  2019    11     27864.02500
347  2019    12     25405.17500
```

And, I have monthly averages in a dataframe called "YMmonthmean" that looks like this -

```
      month  adjusted_power_AVERAGE
7     08    26161.086034
8     09    20707.108319
9     10    25684.728190
10    11    29468.227759
11    12    29509.313319
```

I'm trying to calculate the variability of each "year" value using the adjusted_power_AVERAGE column so that the result looks like this -

[image: required output]

I have tried variations of this below with differing errors. Both the variables YM and YMmonthmean are dataframes. Thank you for your assistance.

```
#NEED VARIABILITY BY MONTH AND YEAR
df_final = (YM.div(YMmonthmean.loc[1], axis=1) - 1)
```

Error most recent:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do? Dividing `YM['adjusted_power']/YMmonthmean['adjusted_power']`per month?

Comment: Hi - sorry, i've edited my question and it should be more clear now. Basically, just averaging the adjusted_power columns for each year (i have years and months from Jan 1991 to Dec 2019 but I'm just showing the year 2019 from Aug - Dec as an example) and month with the corresponding adjusted_power_AVERAGE column for each month.

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to merge both data frames first

```
YM = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019],
                    'month': ['08', '09', '10', '11', '12'],
                   'adjusted_power':[20754.20750, 20305.95125, 18428.88125, 27864.02500, 25405.17500],
})
YMmonthmean = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['08', '09', '10', '11', '12'],
                   'adjusted_power_AVERAGE':[26161.086034, 20707.108319, 25684.728190, 29468.227759, 29509.313319],
})

YM = YM.merge(YMmonthmean, on = 'month', how='left')
YM['var'] = YM['adjusted_power']/ YM['adjusted_power_AVERAGE'] -1
```

results in

```
    year    month   adjusted_power  adjusted_power_AVERAGE  var
0   2019    08      20754.20750     26161.086034            -0.206676
1   2019    09      20305.95125     20707.108319            -0.019373
2   2019    10      18428.88125     25684.728190            -0.282497
3   2019    11      27864.02500     29468.227759            -0.054438
4   2019    12.     25405.17500     29509.313319            -0.139079
```

If you don't want to have the additional columns in there you could drop them afterwards